# What does this convoluted C type declaration mean?

Tags: c, function-pointers, return-type, function-declaration

On a programming community I'm in, someone threw this absolute hand grenade into chat:

> this is a valid function declaration in c
>
> ```c
> void* volatile* (*func(unsigned long const long volatile int, signed, long*[*][42]))(__int128* (*) (int* restrict const[static restrict const 17]));
> ```

Several of us have had a go at trying to decipher this declaration, but nobody's had any luck just yet.

Comment: https://cdecl.org/

Comment: One can write C code of an arbitrary complex level of obfuscation. It doesn't mean that we want to read it.

Comment: @Neil cdecl can't parse that monster.

Comment: @Neil, cdecl.org gives a syntax error for this code.

Comment: @Neil it looks that cdecl cannot parse `int foo(int[const 3])`. It is definitely a bug

Comment: @tstanisl more like a "limitation"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be more easy to understand the function declaration if to represent its declaration

```
void* volatile* (*func(unsigned long const long volatile int, signed, long*[*][42]))(__int128* (*) (int* restrict const[static restrict const 17]));
```

using typedefs.

The first one can be the following

```
typedef _int128* FunctionAsParameter(int* restrict const[static restrict const 17]);
```

The second one is the following

```
typedef void* volatile* FunctionAsReturnType( FunctionAsParameter * );
```

And at last the original function declaration will look like

```
FunctionAsReturnType * func( unsigned long const long volatile int, signed, long*[*][42]);
```

That is the return type of the function `func`  is a pointer to function that has one parameter that in turn is pointer to function.

Comment: This is pretty good! I'd love to see an explanation of how `long*[*][42]` breaks apart and what's meant by `static restrict const 17` in that context although I suspect that's just pointless no-op obfuscation for `long**[42]` and `17`, respectively.

Comment: @fluffy This declaration long*[*][42] is allowed as a parameter declaration of a variable length array of a function declaration that is not at the same time its definition. In fact it does not make a great sense because a parameter having an array type in any case is adjusted by the compiler to pointer to the array element type.

Answer (score 2):

Using the spiral rule:

```
void* volatile* (*func(unsigned long const long volatile int,
                       signed,
                       long*[*][42])
                )(__int128* (*) (int* restrict const[static restrict const 17]));
```

`func` is a function taking a `volatile const unsigned long long`,
an `int` and a pointer to the initial element of a variable length array of arrays of 42 pointers to `long`, returning a pointer to a function *F1* taking a pointer to a function *F2* taking a const pointer to the initial element of an array of at least 17 constant pointers to `int`, returning a pointer to an `__int128`, itself (*F1*) returning a `volatile` pointer to a `void *`... Or something close to that.

- The `restrict` keywords are here for information only in a function prototype.
- qualifying a function argument as `volatile` and or `const` is unusual and probably useless in a function prototype.

Answer (score 1):

This one's actually pretty easy, as the function types do not have names
in their argument lists, so the only name here is the declarator `func`.  So you just start from there and go out.

`func` is followed by `(` so it is a function, and is preceeded by `*` so it returns a pointer to something.  You need to find the matching `)` to find the end of the argument list, which is a little tricky, but when you do, you find another argument list, so the pointer being returned is a pointer to a function, and that function returns the `void * volatile *` in the front of the declaration.  Then you can decode the argument types of the two functions involved, but they're pretty straight-forward, other than the redundant specifiers and qualifiers you can ignore.